# Creating a simple leaderboard without a score field. PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

How would one create a basic leader board ranking each user by quantity?

E.g I am trying to create a leaderboard where it ranks users by who has done the most book reviews

I have tried using the aggregate function but cant seem to figure out how to organise it into a leaderboard. Looking at other tutorials they all seem to have a score field in place to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you storing book reviews in database ?

Comment: A question like this would probably be best presented with your database schema and the current query you are trying. That will ensure you've made a prior effort, and will share with readers how you are thinking about the problem.

Comment: Yes it is stored in a database with the involved field names being
studentid and review

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` r WHERE r.user_id = u.user_id) as user_reviews 
FROM `user` u 
ORDER BY 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` r WHERE r.user_id = u.user_id) DESC
```

Without knowing more details about how you store data etc, the above will list users in order of how many reviews are present in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to make a table in MySQL, then input all the data. Then on the PHP side, when the data would need to be displayed, grab that data from the table and sort it by highest score, and descending. Then present it neatly through HTML and CSS.